# Facebook login in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, storyboard, facebook-login

I'm searching for a guide that can explain to me how I can to create a facebook login in my iOS6 app by using storyboard. So far I haven't found anything. Is there anyone who can help me? I'm searching for a complete guide, or a complete explanation.

If you have time, I will thank you if you helped me with the other facebook features to integrate in my iOS app (sharing, like, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your minimum SDK? You can have 3 types of FB login, with a dialog popup provided by Facebook SDK, by redirecting user to the FB app, or using iOS's own Social framework to do. However, it depends on the Min SDK you are set. below iOS 6 you can't use Social framework.

The complete documention is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/), there are also examples in Facebook SDK download, you can check them out, there are real Xcode projects.

Answer (score 4):

Everything is well explained with tutorial in [Facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)

[Facebook Login on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/)